Create IOTA Verifiable Credential from existing DID?
I am currently trying to create Verifiable Credentials from existing DIDs in my IOTA Sandbox based on the "examples" code from github (https://github.com/iotaledger/identity.rs/blob/main/examples/0_basic/5_create_vc.rs).
I managed to create the credentials but it seems impossible for me to sign them: I used the existing wallet and stronghold (for the issuer), existing DIDs (for issuer and holder) and also managed to resolve these DIDs to DID-Documents in my code. That all works, the problem is the part where I have to call create_credential_jwt(). I have no idea how I can access the fragment variable when using resolved DID-Documents. It works when creating new ones (like in the examples-link above) but how can I access this variable from resolved DIDs?
Here is my code:
    let client: Client = Client::builder()
        .with_primary_node(api_endpoint, None)?
        .finish()
        .await?;

    // Set up resolver
    let mut resolver = Resolver::<IotaDocument>::new();
    resolver.attach_iota_handler(client.clone());

    // Parse and resolve the DIDs
    let issuer_did = IotaDID::parse(did_string_issuer)?;
    let holder_did = IotaDID::parse(did_string_holder)?;

    let issuer_document = resolver.resolve(&issuer_did).await?;
    let holder_document = resolver.resolve(&holder_did).await?;

    println!("{:#}", issuer_document);
    println!("{:#}", holder_document);

   // Set up the issuer's secret manager and storage
    let mut secret_manager_issuer: SecretManager = SecretManager::Stronghold(
        StrongholdSecretManager::builder()
            .password(Password::from(password.to_owned()))
            .build(stronghold_path)?
    );

    // Create storage and load the key from the stronghold
    let mut issuer_storage: MemStorage = MemStorage::new(JwkMemStore::new(), KeyIdMemstore::new());

    // Create a credential subject indicating the degree earned by the Holder.
    let subject: Subject = Subject::from_json_value(json!({
      "id": holder_document.id().as_str(),
      "name": "Holder, BSc",
      "degree": {
        "type": "MastersDegree",
        "name": "Master of Science in Computer Science",
      },
      "GPA": "4.0",
    }))?;

    // Build credential using subject above and issuer.
    let credential: Credential = CredentialBuilder::default()
    .id(Url::parse("https://example.edu/credentials/3732")?)
    .issuer(Url::parse(issuer_document.id().as_str())?)
    .type_("UniversityDegreeCredential")
    .subject(subject)
    .build()?;

    //println!("Credential JSON > {:#}", credential);

    // When creating the credential JWT, use the fragment_issuer variable:
    let credential_jwt: Jwt = issuer_document
    .create_credential_jwt(
      &credential,
      &issuer_storage,
      &fragment, // got this from the link <- wtf is this? How can I get it?
      &JwsSignatureOptions::default(),
      None,
    )
    .await?;

And here is the part on where they get the fragment-variable from in the examples, when creating new DIDs (not in my code like that, because I resolved existing DID-Documents):
  let (_, issuer_document, fragment): (Address, IotaDocument, String) =
    create_did(&client, &mut secret_manager_issuer, &issuer_storage).await?;

Anyone know enough about Rust and/or the IOTA-SDK to help me get this fragment variable from resolved DID-Documents please?
Thank you in advance.

Update: I discovered that my issue stemmed from incorrectly implementing DID creation by following the example code from identity.rs/0_create_did.rs. While the fragment variable was accessible as a String, it wasn't being stored persistently in the Stronghold.
This code must be replaced:
// Set up the issuer's secret manager and storage
let mut secret_manager_issuer: SecretManager = SecretManager::Stronghold(
    StrongholdSecretManager::builder()
        .password(Password::from(password.to_owned()))
        .build(stronghold_path)?
);
// Create storage and load the key from the stronghold
let mut issuer_storage: MemStorage = MemStorage::new(JwkMemStore::new(), KeyIdMemstore::new());

By this:
let stronghold = StrongholdSecretManager::builder()
    .password(password.clone())
    .build(stronghold_path)?;
let stronghold_storage = StrongholdStorage::new(stronghold);
let storage = Storage::new(stronghold_storage.clone(), stronghold_storage.clone());

The key difference is that MemStorage is intended for testing and simulation purposes only - it stores private keys in the RAM rather than persistently in the stronghold. This makes it unsuitable for production use where you need to access these keys across different processes. The corrected code now utilizes Stronghold for persistent, secure storage of private keys during both DID creation and VC creation.

This is not an answer. Please delete this and update instead your question. You do not need to keep track of the history of your insights, as long as you do not invalidate existing answers. Or, hmmm, maybe this IS an answer according to [answer]... in that case please [edit] to make that more obvious and avoid the impression of something that should be an  update to the question.
